# Javascript: Replace string in html without destroying the elements for future event handlers

Tags: javascript

I have this code that searches for a given string of characters (`_aff.tractionsCode`) and replaces it with another string (`tractionsId`), like so:

```
content = document.body.innerHTML.replace(_aff.tractionsCode, tractionsId);
document.body.innerHTML = content;
```

Here's an example:

Assume `_aff.tractionsCode` is equal to {tractionsCode}

```
<div class="affiliate" rel="{tractionsCode}">{tractionsCode}</div>
```

It would need to replace both instances of {tractionsCode}

However, the problem is once this happens, it is replacing the loaded html so other javascript event handlers, which I may or (most likely) may not have access to, no longer function properly.

Is there a way to look through the html (including attributes like rel) and run the replace without overwriting all the html?

Or is there a better way entirely?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going via `innerHTML` of the `body` is going to overwrite everything. You need to search for the specific text nodes that you want to replace.

Something like..

```
document.getElementBy..('identifier').innerHTML
```

In jQuery,

```
$('.className').text('text to insert');
```

Comment: Yes but I want to replace every instance of it in the html. And unfortunately I do not have access to jQuery for this particular project. Should I just create a function that loops through every element in <body>?

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, you could loop through the expected matching elements. Any other way that replaces DOM elements would destroy the `data` and `events` associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch! What you're trying to do is probably possible with lots of work and iterating over nodes (not elements)... but why bother? Such work is made easiest by a combination of templates scoped to a subsection of the DOM and event handlers that make use of delegation.

JSRender (https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) is the replacement for the previous jQuery template plugin (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl), but jquery-tmpl is still rather usable (I believe pandora still uses it). You can store templates in script blocks using a non-javascript type and easily pull that content to render and replace a specific subsection of the DOM:

```
<script id="affiliateThing" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="affiliate" rel="${transactionsCode}">${transactionsCode}</div>
</script>
<script>
    jQuery("#affiliateThing").
        tmpl([{'transactionsCode': 'wee'}]).
        appendTo("#someElement");
</script>
```

To ensure that replacing this markup doesn't break any event handlers, make sure to delegate events via a parent element:

```
jQuery("#someElement").on("click", ".affiliate", function(event){alert('wee');});
```

This statement binds the event handler to "#someElement" and not the individual ".affiliate" elements, but only fires the handler if the event originated from a ".affiliate" element.

Enjoy!

EDIT: The backend library for this and templating system is completely unimportant. The technique, however, is. Mix scoped templating and delegated events and you're golden.

Comment: Is there a way to do this to the entire body and/or without modifying the html?